# Fire function when div is scrolled to | jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is it possible that if a div is scrolled to, it should execute a function, like for example:

[image]

Yes? No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() <= $("div#14").position().top && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("div#14").position().top) {
    if ($("div#14").position().top + $("div#14").height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      do_something();
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT** Sorry, I put the ">=" and "<=" wrong.

Watch it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cBdhk/4/

**EDIT 2** I updated the link but forgot updating the code.

Comment: You have a typo: `$(this).heigth()` but it doesn't seem to work though. Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PjLPq/ (note: use Firebug to look into the console log).

Answer (score 0):

With https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-on-scrolled-to it's

```
$('.my-div').onScrolledTo(1,
    function() {
        alert('.my-div element became fully visible');
    }
);
```